# How to embed youtube videos in webpage for mobile Safari?

Tags: html, youtube, mobile-safari, mobile-website, html5-video

I want to add a vertical list of **youtube** videos with thumbnails and then if user click on any video it should be played full screen and whenever user will return to thumbnail page he should return on same location(Video).

I need to do this for Mobile website which is for iphone and Android.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Comment: I need to add lots of videos with thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

Works on Safari on iphone  and Android Mobile browser also

```html
<iframe width="593" height="334" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```